# Golang: How to simulate a POST with a form request?

Tags: go, server

I've been scouring the internet and can't find much at all about posting forms in golang tests. This is my attempt at it. I get the error "dial tcp: too many colons in address ::1" though. If I change the address to "http://localhost:8080/" I get "dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connection refused".

I've read that if you put the (IPv6) address in brackets, the brackets will fix the problem, but then I get the error unrecognized protocol.

```
var addr = "http://::1/"
h := handlers.GetHandler()
server := httptest.NewServer(h)
server.URL = addr
req, err := http.PostForm(addr+"login",
        url.Values{"username": {"lemonparty"}, "password": {"bluewaffle"}})
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Comment: `http.PostForm` does not give you a `http.Request` it gives you a `http.Response`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tl;dr the `Listener` in `httptest.Server` doesn't use the `httptest.Server.URL` as the url to listen on. It doesn't care what that value is. It listens on local hosts lowest open port number.

The URL property on `httptest.Server` is not really doing anything. Change it all you want, just don't send your requests there. Check out this example program https://play.golang.org/p/BsH38WLkrJ

Basically, if I change the servers URL then send the request to the value I set it to it doesn't work, but if I send it to the default value it does.

Also check out the source http://golang.org/src/net/http/httptest/server.go?s=415:1018#L65, as well as the certs at the bottom of the file; clearly hard coded for the lowest open port on local host. If you want to make request to another URL the `Listener`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. server.ListenAndServe() is undefined though. http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/

Comment: @ChrisW oh yeah I'm a fool, was thinking you're using the http package. I'll edit with a sensible answer.

Comment: @ChrisW yeah that URL property isn't actually reflective of where your server is listening. Did a little testing, it just continues listening on localhost:2 no matter what. If you send somewhere else you'll get connection refused.

Comment: Or more simply stated, `httptest.Server`'s `URL` field is an output, not an input.